# HANA Migrations with FlyWay

Tags: flyway, hana

simple question, is HANA supported by FlyWay?
Especially SQLScript?
I found no infos on either HANA nor FlyWAy webpages. Is there ongoing development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support right now. Feel free to file an enhancement request in the issue tracker. Pull request welcome.

**Update:** This is now supported